# How to include Flash builder project as Library in android Studio?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, android-library

I have been looking for a solution to this in stackover flow.
How can i add a Flash builder project as a library in android studio?
This is my situation.There are to projects dependent on each other.

- Authentication module
- Core app(this has been been migrated to flash builder)

How do i add the core app(which is in flash builder ) as a library to the authentication module?

Comment: Adobe dropped support for Flash on Android [about three years ago](http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/28/adobe-confirms-it-wont-support-flash-on-android-4-1/).

Comment: i am using this flash builder app which works on android github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-air-client .this i want to be the library for authentication module which is in java

Comment: The Flash Builder project compiles the MXML and Actionscript into an APK, not an Android library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you can achieve your proposed solution but I do know you can do it the other way round: add native Android code to  a Flash Builder project, through the Native Extension (ANE) system. More info here ([Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)).